# Animate on bézier with ScrollMagic: Initial state = first bézier point

Tags: animation, css-transitions, gsap, scrollmagic

**[See a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jqmhuc9y/5/)**

I am tweening along a bézier path with 3 points.

```
// bezier data
var bezierData = {
  curviness: 1,
  autoRotate: false,
  values: [
    {x: 0,  y: 0, rotation:"40_cw"}, /* <-- The desired state of the object before any animation has happened */
    {x: 20,  y: 0, rotation:"0_ccw"},
    {x: 40, y:0, rotation:"-20_ccw"}
  ]
};

// build tween
var tween = new TimelineMax()
          .add(TweenMax.to("#testobj", 1, {css:{bezier: bezierData}, ease:Power1.easeInOut}));

// create scene
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: "#testobj",
        duration: 100,
        offset: 10
    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(ctrl)
    .addIndicators();
```

**What I want:** The initial state of my object (i.e. before any animation has happened) should be the first bézier point, `{x: 0,  y: 0, rotation:"40_cw"}`.

**What's happening:** The initial state is the object's default style, i.e. the equivalent of `{x: 0,  y: 0, rotation:"0"}`. Note how in the jsfiddle the green square starts out upright while I want it to start rotated 40° clock-wise.

Comment: perhaps you can use **`.set()`** before doing the **`.to()`** tween? something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/jqmhuc9y/6/)**.

Comment: Perfect! I'll add this as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tahir Ahmed's answer works!

> perhaps you can use `.set()` before doing the `.to()` tween? something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/jqmhuc9y/6/).